# How to download a Word file in Spring with AJAX call?

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, spring-mvc, doc

I want to download a `.doc` file, but I am getting some warning:

> #[http-nio-8080-exec-9] WARN 
>       org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver
>       Handler execution resulted in exception: Failed to instantiat e standard 
>       serializer (of type com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.NullSerializer): 
>       Class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BasicSerializerFactory can not 
>       access a member of class 
>       com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.NullSerializer with modifiers 
>       "private"

My controller goes to the service method and can get the path of the file.

```
function downloadDocument  ()  {

    var docName = $('.sampleFile').text();
    var questionType = $('#questionType').val();
    var questionLanguage = $('#questionLanguage').val();
    alert(docName);
    $.ajax({
        url : "downloadSample",
        async : false,
        type : "GET",
        data : "documentName" : docName ,
        contentType : "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
        dataType : "json",
        success : function(data){
            alert(data);
        }
    });

}
```

The Spring controller is:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/downloadSample", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json;charset=UTF-8")
public void sampleFileDownload( @RequestParam(value = "documentName") String documentName) {

    String realPath = context.getRealPath("") + "static" + File.separator + "sampleFile" + File.separator + questionType + File.separator + questionLanguage + File.separator + documentName;

    try {
        File file = new File(realPath);
        logger.debug("REal path in sample Document " + realPath);
        InputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
        String mimeType = URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromStream(inputStream);
        if (mimeType == null) {
            mimeType = "application/octet-strem";
        }
        response.setContentType(mimeType);
        response.setContentLength((int) file.length());
        response.setHeader("Content-Diposition", String.format("attachement; filename=\"%s\"", file.getName()));

        FileCopyUtils.copy(inputStream, response.getOutputStream());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Give the solution as soon as possible.

Comment: How is the response defined?

Comment: @Autowired
 HttpServletResponse response;

Comment: Try removing 'produces = "application/json;charset=UTF-8"' from the method header

Comment: But it show the same warning nad can't able to download

Comment: please any one can help as soon as possible .

Comment: Hear i am using spring security also. Now it makes no error or warning message but file is not downloaded.